# floated div Overlapping non floated div

Tags: html, css-float

These two div are defined in body tag 
The problem is they are overlapping each other div(color yellow) goes to the left of the page as expected but the second div (red color) in which the float is not styled comes underneath the first div

Why second div(red color) is not coming beside the first div, second div should wrap around the first div because of the float property

however visual studio 2010 is producing the desired result but chrome, firefox,jsfiddle does not

```
<div style ="background-color:Yellow;height:300px; width:300px; float:left"> </div>
<div style ="background-color:red;height:300px; width:300px"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` to the red div if your goal is to have them both floating left but not overlapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/42o54e4w/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am curious to know why they are overlapping

Comment: @FahadMeraj - When you float an element, you're taking it out of the normal document flow. Basically, its position won't affect other elements on the page unless they're floating as well. Since the red div wasn't floating, it was just ignoring the yellow div completely.

Comment: But then why the <p> tag successfully wraps around it, but in my case red div is not wrapping around it ?

Answer (score 0):

The float property works on the element you apply it to and also the element it is relative to. If an element does not have a float property it will not try and float to left/right.
The second div should also have a float property.

Please read this to make it more clear - https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/